# How to change/modify an event in <img> tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to little help. I have an "img" tag, therein an "ondblclick" event, that calls a function. This function changes the "img"-s "src" attribute. It works so far. But, I would like change the event in same function, for example, I would like for the changed image works only with the "onclick" event, but again, the "ondblclick" event is working. Why?

```
function Something_Change(cikkszamid,cikkid,kiszereles,me)
{
   var input_field = document.getElementById(cikkszamid);
   var imgchanges = document.getElementById(cikkid);
   imgchange.src = '<?php echo url::base().'media/images/shopping_cart.png' ?>';
   imgchange.setAttribute("width", "24");
   imgchange.setAttribute("height", "24");
   imgchange.style.cursor = "pointer";
   imgchange.onclick = Another_Something_Change(cikkszamid,cikkid,kiszereles,me);
   input_field.disabled = false;
   input_field.style.color = "red";
   input_field.style.borderColor = "red";
   input_field.style.borderWidth = "2px";
}
```

Comment: `ondblclick` should be a function, so `imgchange.ondblclick = event => Another_Something_Change(cikkszamid,cikkid,kiszereles,me)`

Answer (score 0):

because double clicking it is registering two click events. If you want it to specifically do nothing for a double click, add an event handler for double click and in the function prevent the default:

```
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```